# How do I get this jquery image slider to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just noticed that when I click left or right on on my image slider, it's triggering the same action and therefore left and right are pointless!

You'll notice next() and previous() are exactly the same!

This code is third party and I'm not too sure how to correct it. Any suggestions?

```
/* Sidebar image slider */
$('.image_slider').each(function () {

    var $slider=$(this), $slides= $slider.find('.slides'), imageSliderInterval;

    /* Functions */
    function next () {
        $slides.children(':last').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).prependTo($slides).fadeIn(1);
        });
    }
    function previous () {
        $slides.children(':last').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).prependTo($slides).fadeIn(1);
        });
    }

    /* Initialize */


    /* Controls */
    $slider.find('.left').click(function () {
        next();
    });
    $slider.find('.right').click(function () {
        previous();
    });

});
```

This is the image code:

```
   <section class="image_slider grid_4">
    <nav class="slider_nav"> <a href="#" class="left">&nbsp;</a> <a href="#" class="right">&nbsp;</a> <p class="message_overlay">Click images to enlarge</p> 
    </nav>
    <div class="slides">
        <a href="0003.jpg" rel="fancybox_club_corner" title=""><img src="0003.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="0002.jpg" rel="fancybox_club_corner" title=""><img src="0002.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="0001.jpg" rel="fancybox_club_corner" title=""><img src="0001.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Here is it in action:
http://dev.enterf1.com/test.php

Comment: can you provide us a fiddle..??

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle

Comment: Not a fiddle but a example uploaded, see original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging, i think this is the solution. Change the code of the next and previous function according to this:

```
function next () {
    $slides.children(':last').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $slides.children(':last').remove().prependTo($slides).fadeIn(1);
        });
}
function previous () {
    $slides.children(':first').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $slides.children(':first').remove().appendTo($slides).fadeIn(1);                
    });
}
```

Comment: This works with a slight modification. previous() needs fadeOut(1 and fadeIn(500) - the opposite of next(). thanks man"